# .Net XML parser or others?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing

As a part of my academics, i'm asked to build a web content management system using .Net framework and xml databases. I have heard that .net itself provides a XML parser. Is it good enough for academic projects or is there any other 3rd party applications I can use?

Comment: Since you did not provide you criteria for what is "good enough" it is not possible to answer... But .Net XML related API (`XmlReader`, `XmlDocument`, `XDocument`) are following standards (XML 1.0 only), so likely you find it suitable for academic purposes. Note that if you need [1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/) you need to find other libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with Linq to XML
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx

That is the standard way of interacting with xml from .Net.